# Bind on non-recursive mode doesn't work

Tags: networking, dns

I installed bind for caching server and recursive mode works well. But Non-recursive modes doesn't work well.

Here are option contents of `/etc/named.conf` (For recursive)

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 {localhost; any;};
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24;any; };
        allow-query-cache { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; any;};
        recursion yes;


        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};
```

The result says :

```
[root@localhost ~]# nslookup naver.com
Server:         192.168.0.220
Address:        192.168.0.220#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   naver.com
Address: 125.209.222.142
Name:   naver.com
Address: 202.179.177.22
Name:   naver.com
Address: 202.179.177.21
Name:   naver.com
Address: 125.209.222.141
```

Here are another option contents of /etc/named.conf (For Non-recursive)

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 {localhost; any;};
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24;any; };
        allow-query-cache { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; any;};
        recursion no;


        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};
```

The result says :

```
[root@localhost ~]# nslookup naver.com
Server:         192.168.0.220
Address:        192.168.0.220#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find naver.com: No answer
```

Why is that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a recursive query, a name server behaves like a client and asks
>   another name server to either provide it with the answer to its query,
>   or to return an error because it cannot supply an answer.

That you have.

You can turn off globally recursion with `recursion no;` but allow it to your request with

```
 allow-recursion {192.168.0.0/24;}; //change IPs as required
```

Also you can configure "forwarders" to fw dns request before trying to find the answer itself by iterative query to other name servers including those in the root domain.